# Set structure value for specified object with Ramda lens

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, lenses

Given this lens:

```
const obj = {
  foo: ['bar', 'qux']
}

const foo0Lens = R.lensPath(['foo', 0]);
```

`R.set` sets `foo` first element to specified value on variable object:

```
R.set(foo0Lens, 'baz')(obj);
```

While I need a function that sets `foo` first element on specified object to variable value:

```
const setObjFoo0 = R.flip(R.set(foo0Lens))(obj);    
setObjFoo0('baz');
```

`R.flip` does the job but argument joggling makes the code less expressive.

Is it how it supposed to be done? Am I missing something about Ramda lenses? Are there other ways to conveniently create `setObjFoo0` with lenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might be cleaner:

```
const setObjFoo0 = R.set(foo0Lens, R.__, obj)
```

It reads better to my mind, when not using the `R.` prefix:

```
const setObjFoo0 = set(foo0Lens, __, obj)
```

There the placeholder looks like a placeholder.

There has been sporadic talk about removing the placeholders from Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors), but nothing seems imminent.  And examples like this help make the case that it is sometimes significantly cleaner to use it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about a placeholder. Indeed, this is the solution. I hope they won't be removed because this seems to be one of many use cases for them.